# Solve the equation: $12^{r-1}=7r$

Tags: logarithms

$12^{r-1}=7r$.  I teach an Algebra 2 class, and I came across this question in one of their homework sets on logarithms.  Surely this is a typo and should read $12^{r-1}=7$.  I'm not sure how to solve it the other way around.  Could anyone point me in the right direction on this problem?

Comment: I highly suspect it's a typo. A solution to this would require Lambert's W function or numerical methods, the latter of which would be more likely for students of Algebra 2.

Comment: Ah, OK, yes probably so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equations of the form $a^x-bx=0$ can be solved using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
Assuming a,b are positive, we have 
$$
e^{x\log(a)}=\frac{b}{\log(a)}x\log(a).
$$
Putting $y=-x\log(a)$ we obtain
$$
e^{-y}=-\frac{b}{\log(a)}y,
$$
so that
$$
ye^y=-\frac{\log(a)}{b}.
$$
Then we have 
$y=W(-\frac{\log(a)}{b})$, which gives
$$
x=-\frac{W(-\frac{\log(a)}{b})}{\log(a)}.
$$
Above we could multiply the equation by $12$ to obtain
$$
12^x=72 x.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Seeing it is Algebra 2, another alternative to a typo is that the equation
$$
12^{r-1}=7r
$$
is correct, but not over the real numbers, but for a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$.
Then we would read it as
$$
12^{r-1}\equiv 7r \bmod p.
$$
For example, with $p=5$ we have a solution $r=4$, because
$$
1728=12^{3}\equiv 7\cdot 4 =28\bmod 5.
$$